# SASS how to round floating point result of division 1/3 to 33.33334?

Tags: floating-point, sass

In SASS by dividing `1/3` result is `33.33333`, and browser sum-up three elements of this size to `99.984`. What i need is exactly number `100`, and this can be achieved by stacking three elements of size `33.33334`. How can I force SASS to to round up the last number of division?

demo: http://sassmeister.com/gist/577dec6f9b85b70c3621

Comment: Why did I get down vote for this question?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, solution was to use external function written by *Terkel*.

His decimal-rounding functions: https://gist.github.com/terkel/4373420

Usage

```
.tile {
  &-1-3 {
    width: decimal-ceil(100/3, 5);
    // this should result as 33.33334%;
  }
  &-2-3 {
    width: 2/3 * 100%;
  }
  &-1-1 {
    width: 3/3 * 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to roll your own rounding method using multiplication, division, and `ceil()`.

```
.tile {
  &-1-3 {
    $num: 1 / 3; // 0.33333
    // the number we multiply by should have the same number of
    // zeros as there are decimal places you want to keep + the
    // number of digits there will be on the left side of the decimal
    $num: $num * 10000000; // 3333333.33333
    // ceil to round up
    $num: ceil($num); // 3333334
    // divide by that amount again
    $num: $num / 10000000; // 33.33334
    width: $num * 100%; // 33333.34%
  }
}
```